# Projection of tensor in vectorial space

Tags: vector-spaces, tensors, trace, projection

Let us consider the closed convex cone of Sym (Sym be the subspaces of Lin constituted by all symmetric tensors)

K={**A**∈ Sym such that *tr***A** ≤ 0 }

For each **E**∈ Sym determine the projection P(**E**) of **E** onto K

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.